# Django call a class based view from another class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have two classes corresponding to two different forms. When one is submitted, i need to call the other one.

```
class FormsPreInput(CreateView):
    template_name = "form_preinput.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = preinput_form()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = preinput_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return FormsInput.as_view()(request=self.request)

class FormsInput(CreateView):
    template_name = "input_form.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("inside input get")
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("inside post ")
```

So the problem is the code is FormsInput is being called using the POST request object, so the code goes to FormsInput.post() without going to FormsInput.get()

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, this is not how Django views are designed to be used. Better to factor out the common code that both views need to execute into a separate function and call that from both views.